# Why put Psalm 130 right before barchu?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, tehilim-psalms, aseres-yemei-teshuva

I've seen the custom quoted in many siddurim to recite [Psalm 130](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16351) (שיר המעלות ממעמקים), with the Ark open, between ישתבח and ברכו during עשרת ימי תשובה. This particular Psalm was chosen because [it's very apropos for the time period](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45911/5323), since it deals with forgiveness for sins.

Given that, why say it particularly there? Is there something special about that part of davening?

Comment: Note some recite it before Tachanun.

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't know that. Where'd you see that? ( *personal experience, a specific sefer, etc* )

Comment: Note: The Vilna Gaon [apparently] didn't approve of this practice. The Yekkes don't do it either.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Thanks for that info; I didn't know that. Where is this brought down?

Comment: @Shokhet - The Gro siddurim all mention not to say it, and the Yekkishe ones don't even acknowledge the custom exists.

Comment: @Shokhet -fascinating info about this "spot" in the Aruch Hashulchan, but it doesn't answer your specific question. - סימן נד - דינים השייכים ל''ישתבח'' (http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0053_L2)

Comment: @Isaac thanks for the bounty! (Hoping bounty-ers get pinged by comments)

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19621&st=&pgnum=274&hilite= is the original source (bottom of the first column). I don't see any explanation for the chosen location (not that I understand any of what is being said).

Comment: Although Psalms are recited in other sections of Shacharit, perhaps, the answer may involve enothing more than the concept that Psukei Dezimra is the main section for saying Psalms, and this was the optimal place for this? I also suspect that the phrase "From the depths I call to you" has some significance to a "higher" level of Shacharit as we enter Kri'at Shema which has more holiness and significance than Psukei Dezimra.

Comment: @DanF it's after pesukei dezimra, not in.

Comment: Chabad doesn't open the ark

Comment: @user613 You're most likely correct. However, I need to check a source if technically Kaddish is what ends Pd"z.

Comment: @DanF Pesukei dezimra is the berachah that starts with Baruch she'amar and ends with yishtabach (shu"a classifieds it as one berachah, but I'm not sure if shu"a is clear about whether it's called PD)

Comment: Probably just a late addition. Even shirat hayam (and in some places haazinu) was originally added *after* yishtabach, before being collected inside the brachot.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to add this to our prayer this is practically the best place. Before Baruch She'amar is before we start, especially in Nusach Ashkenaz, and would not be an actual part of the prayer. After Shmona Esrei is too late. We can't add it to Birchas Krias Shma and we don't want to add something to Psukei d'Zimra either, being that it is considered a Bracha.

Pesukei d'Zimra is where we recite chapters of Tehillim and so it fits best as being attached to it.

Comment: We add stuff to Pesukei Dizimra every Saturday morning so that shouldn't be a problem at all, especially bc this is Tehillim. Why is after Shmone Esrei too late? Why not during Tachanun? Is Avinu Malkeinu not part of prayer?

Comment: @DoubleAA, could there perhaps be a difference between adding a set list of tehillim to P"Z on Shabbat and adding a perek just because you like it? Also, the tehillim in P"Z for Shabbat have been part of sidrei tefillah for much longer than Ps. 130, which I've heard was added by talmidei haAri.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt There _could_ be. I don't see any reason to make such a distinction though, considering for example that the MB permits one to say Hallel during PdZ if one is late to Shul. And the extra stuff on Shabbat has not been around that much longer than the Ari. Pesukei Dizimra used to be just (some of) Tehillim 145-150. Everything else is already "extra" because someone liked it.

Comment: @DoubleAA interestingly some Rishonim held that the post-talmudic additions to pesukkei d'zimra constitute a prohibited hefsek. (I remember seeing this in the Sefer HaBatim). He writes that the practice to say them is a mistake.

Comment: @DoubleAA The Arizal didn't add anything to Nusach Ashkenaz. Whoever added the Minhag of שיר המעלות was doing it as a mere Minhag as did not add it to the Pesukei d'Zimra.

Comment: I know he didn't add it to PdZ. The question is why didn't he. He certainly could have. You can add all the Tehillim you want to PdZ. See the Tur and DM http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x136 that Tehillim added for various Minhagim are included in the Bracha of Baruch SheAmar. Since he could have, why didn't he?

Comment: @DoubleAA That is not about adding what you want. The Tur merely says to follow your Minhag of what to say. Yes, there are ancient Minhagim of what to include in Psukei d'Zimra but that is not about adding things when you want just because of a relevance.

Comment: What is the difference between "ancient" and newer minhagim in this regard? Neither is original and hence still no bracha problems.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not saying it is an actual problem of a Hefsek in a Bracha, since it is after all Tehillim. Nor is PdZ an actual Bracha. That is why I worded it this way. In Birchas Krias Shma we can't, in PdZ we didn't wasn't to, since it is after all between Brachos -- a fact mentioned by Poskim as a reason to be weary of Hefsek.

Comment: Which poskim mention such a worry by adding in Tehillim?

Comment: @DoubleAA As for the difference, this is recited because of its relevance to the time, not inserted to be part of PdZ. My point is that we don't play with PdZ to insert Tefillos the way we would in שומע תפילה, Korbanos and after Shmona Esrei. If a Kehilla inserted some chapters than we keep it.

Comment: That's an arbitrary distinction that you just made up. We do add Mizmor leDavid on certain days and certain paragraphs on Shabbatot and Yamim Tovim plus Hoshana Rabba in some places. There's no reason different days can't have extra parts. Not to mention my point above about Hallel.

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't say anyone Paskens not to say Tehillim. I said they refer to this area as a semi אמצע ברכות. There are no Yehi Ratzons composed for this part.

Comment: There is an often-quoted statement:
 השח בין ישתבח לברכו עבירה היא בידו וחוזר עליה מעורכי המלחמה - One who speaks between Yishtabah and Barakhu has sinned and would be able to be evacuated from combat on account of the fear he carries regarding his guilt in this matter.